# How can I get the correct url to the video file from an embedded video?

Tags: java, android, url, video

I want to get the actual Video File Url from an embedded video on any website. It essentially is not YouTube. It can be any website.
I am coding for android on Java.

For Example :
The thing I want to do is same as this IDM button does :

[image: IDM "Download this video" Button]

[Actually not the same because the button there captures a network stream when it gets started by the player. But I want to get the file straight from the player.]
Is there a way to attain this? Can Any external Library [e.g. Jsoup] do this?

I am already using Jsoup to get some other contents of the page but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: No problem! I got it already. But It would be better if someone depicted me any universal method that works for every embedded video. In This video it had the URL exposed in the source as a query. I just needed to find it out. So, Jsoup would be able to do it

Comment: Which player do you use? If the player is different each time, like when you open the web page from the browser, then get the cache dir: getApplicationContext().getCacheDir() and search for some files with a certain extension (you'll have to enumerate them (avi,3gp etc.), if this is what you mean by getting the file "straight" from the player (I can't think of any other way).

Comment: Actually, I mentioned that It would be great if it was a universal method.[I have found the solution for the particular player but in future I would like to include support for others too, and that's why.] I know this is kinda tricky. But I don't know if there is any better solution than capturing the stream just like IDM. And I will be using nothing more than a standalone app which would be streaming videos so there is no question of Browser.

Comment: you have no way to do it because there is no standard on that. you have to do code that is flexible enough to add the different players specs.

Comment: @Writwick can u please tell me the solution u found for getting the url of a specific player...

Comment: @Writwick can u please tell me the solution u found for getting the url of a specific player... –

Answer (score 1):

If your using jsoup you can get the url quite easily. Just use jsoup to select all the possible video tags (`<iframe>`, `<videos>`, `<embed>`, etc). Then get the `src` attribute and store that where you want it:

Example

```
//Standard Jsoup search
Elements iframes = body.select("iframe");

/*Gets the src of all the iframes or other tag, and if you have
multiple videos you might have to do this in a for loop.*/    
String videoURL = iframes.attr("src");
```

Comment: I don't think the `src` field contains the direct URL to the video file. If it did contain, I wouldn't have posted this question here! I have thoroughly checked up the html code of the site (and decided to use jsoup to parse it to get info) but I could not find the URL in the source. Even I bet it can't contain the direct URL. Most probably It contains the link to the page where the video is embedded so that it can display the contents of the page within the `iframe` or the similar tags.....

Answer (score -1):

As you may know that different website have different video downloading strategies, some might give a real url in html file for directly download, others may just return video stream while click button or touch screen.
while so many different strategies on video download its really hard for you to find a universal way to fetch a real url to start a download task. But here I have an idea, not so smart, it can be very dumb:

1.play a video in the background(to let browser download that video in browser cache).
2.find that cache file and extract video file which you want.

for myself, I usually have some videos that I want but can not be downloaded straightly, thus I will use IE to play that video and find that video in IE temporary folder.
wish I could help you!

Comment: As you may have seen I am trying to do this on android. There is no IE. Plus there is no flash support in 4.1+ androids. So I cannot always play the video to capture the stream. If you do a bit research with chrome developer tools, You can see that a new stream opens up when the play button is clicked. From there an URL to the streaming file can be got without any hassle. But in no way I can play the video in the android browser or webview dynamically, at least I can't think of any way. And of flash, it isn't supported in 4.0+. So I have to get another way round...