# Find streaming video in webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, html5-video

Actually my goal is to implement a webview and catch the url of streaming video in webview.
I tried so many codes but no result. Here my code i tried so far
 `

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println("link"+url);

        } else if (url.startsWith("http://www.youtube.com")
                || url.startsWith("https://www.youtube.com")
                || url.startsWith("http://m.youtube.com")
                || url.startsWith("https://m.youtube.com")) {
            Intent urlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(url));
            urlIntent.putExtra(mPackageName + ".Origin", 1);
            mActivity.startActivity(urlIntent);
            return true;


        } else if (url.startsWith("magnet:?")) {
            Intent urlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(url));
            urlIntent.putExtra(mPackageName + ".Origin", 1);
            mActivity.startActivity(urlIntent);
        } else if (url.startsWith("intent://")) {
            Intent intent = null;
            try {
                intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                return false;
            }
            if (intent != null) {
                try {
                    mActivity.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(Constants.LOGTAG, "ActivityNotFoundException");
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
```

Comment: u mean live video u wanna show in webview?

Comment: @adcom i want to catch streaming video url from webview.
for ex:- i opened a video inside webview and i hit play button to play then the video is playing it means streaming to the webview so i want to find the url of the streaming video.

Comment: ohh ok is ur webview landing to overdien method?

Comment: @adcom  i tried Override but not working

Answer (score 0):

I have found a jar which extracts all links from url may be that help you 
basically there are 2 jars

1. [HTML parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/download)

I hv worked with jsoup jar and wriiten below code : that extracted all links from url and gave me now u can sort it and get ur useful urls

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new AsyncTask().execute();

    }

    class AsyncTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Document doc;
            try {

                // need http protocol
                doc = Jsoup.connect(
                        "http://video.nationalgeographic.com/").get();

                // get page title
                String title = doc.title();
                System.out.println("title : " + title);

                // get all links
                Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                for (Element link : links) {

                    // get the value from href attribute
                    System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
                    System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @SinilkumarSinu this is my working code i hv just trying plz see it and hv toasted url and worked for me..i can pass u complete project too

Comment: Thanks i will check and let you know

Comment: Code is working but we need the video original url.This code i test with this url http://vimeo.com/m/100554421 but i got the same "http://vimeo.com/m/100554421"

Comment: u can use  webView.getOriginalUrl();

Comment: just put        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, view.getOriginalUrl(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); in onpagestarted method

Comment: No toast , toast was empty.

Comment: go back and come agiain from activity

Comment: Now i got toast but my  problem is not fixed.Url vimeo.com/m/100554421 i can see video inside the webview but i want the original url to download the video now i can get vimeo.com/m/100554421 in toast to downloadable url.I need video streaming url not vimeo.com/m/100554421

Comment: when i hit a play in iframe video inside webview i want to get the video url in .mp4/.flv format not page original url

Comment: one quuestion i wanna ask little bit confused ...is this question similar u r willing to ask?-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140124/how-can-i-get-the-correct-url-to-the-video-file-from-an-embedded-video

Comment: Yes. it is the same way.

Comment: ohh ok , i can try to answer this but is it specify website or any like above question?

Comment: is it possible to catch streaming video url inside webview? 
not for specify website it for all videos

Comment: 1st of all i don't need that button http://i.stack.imgur.com/RMt2w.png
and no need other browser integration, just inside my webview just hit play button in the iframe to play video and  i need the original video url to download. Thats it .

Comment: got it let me try..intersting question

Comment: i will post my updated answer after some time but that will help u to much extend i think

Comment: i think so will u plz help me a little can u post some sample urls and its output u excepting....for example what if one html page hv multiple .mp3 files then ???

Comment: what if one html page hv multiple .mp4 files then ?

Comment: this is the normal url of video  vimeo.com/100554421 , but the download url is this http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/23696/677/269940937.mp4?token2=1406807309_c964f92b741fc3a720c2564b07411782&aksessionid=5a827076e87b196f

Comment: can you post the project src file?